# Get first string before separator?

Tags: php, string, explode, separator

I have strings with folowing structure:

```
7_string_12
7_string2_122
7_string3_1223
```

How I can get string before second "_" ?

I want my final result to be :

```
7_string
7_string2
7_string3
```

I am using explode('_', $string) and combine first two values, but my script was very slow!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$str = '7_string_12';
echo substr($str,0,strrpos($str,'_'));
```

echoes

```
7_string
```

no matter what's at the begining of the string

Comment: Thanks ! I've another question! How to make this code to show me the following result : string ? That is to show string between separators. Thanks in advance !

Comment: @dilyan_kn `preg_match('/_(\S+)_/',$str,$m); echo $m[1];`

Comment: Please note, `substr($str,0,strrpos($str,'_'))` is OK if the input isn't like `7_string2_abc_123`. Because the output will be `7_string2_abc`.

Answer (score 1):

If it always starts with 7_ you can try this:

```
$string = substr($text, 0, strpos($text, '_', 2));
```

The strpos() searches for the first _ starting from character 3 (= s from string). Then you use substr() to select the whole string starting from the first character to the character returned by strpos().

Answer (score 1):

```
$s1 = '7_string_12';
echo substr($s1, 0, strpos($s1, '_', 2));
```

Comment: The assumption that the first token is always one character long is a bit dangerous.